# How to close previous opened div if you click on the next one inside a forEach loop?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple JS code that, on click toggles and opens a div as an accordion/faq item.

Now, when I click on one and click again it will close. But if I click on the next one while the clicked is open I want to close the previous one.

I want to remove the "open" close if the current div is open, and clicked on the next one.

Codepen included: https://codepen.io/Merdzanovich/pen/MWvaryG

My code:

```
(() => {
    const accordion = document.querySelector('[bke-data="accordion"]');

    if (!accordion) {
        return;
    }

    const items = accordion.querySelectorAll('.accordion__item');

    items.forEach((item) => {
        item.addEventListener('click', () => item.classList.toggle('open'));
    });
})();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion" bke-data="accordion">
                    <div class="accordion__item">
                        <div class="accordion__topbar">
                            <p class="accordion__text">How long does delivery take?</p>
                            <span class="accordion__arrow"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion__box">
                            <p class="accordion__content">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque perspiciatis inventore
                                sapiente commodi id consectetur ducimus ipsa fugiat officiis nesciunt blanditiis
                                temporibus quas aperiam, voluptas.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="accordion__item">
                        <div class="accordion__topbar">
                            <p class="accordion__text">How long do I have to return my purchase?</p>
                            <span class="accordion__arrow"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion__box">
                            <p class="accordion__content">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque perspiciatis inventore
                                sapiente commodi id consectetur ducimus ipsa fugiat officiis nesciunt blanditiis
                                temporibus quas aperiam, voluptas.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="accordion__item">
                        <div class="accordion__topbar">
                            <p class="accordion__text">I ordered too many, can I update my order?</p>
                            <span class="accordion__arrow"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion__box">
                            <p class="accordion__content">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque perspiciatis inventore
                                sapiente commodi id consectetur ducimus ipsa fugiat officiis nesciunt blanditiis
                                temporibus quas aperiam, voluptas.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets", how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993)

Comment: You'll either need to brute force "close" all divs (for loop) and then open the div clicked. Or maintain the state of the current open div and simply close that one when the next is clicked. There are a number of other scenarios, but why re-invent the wheel? Bootstrap has a good [Accordion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/accordion/) component.

Comment: https://code-boxx.com/simple-vanilla-javascript-accordion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reworked your code a little into a minimal, working example - the trick is to find any already open items and close them before you open your new accordion item:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    let accordion = document.querySelector(".accordion"), 
        items = accordion.querySelectorAll(".accordion__item");

    items.forEach((item) => {
        item.addEventListener("click", () => {
            let openItems = document.querySelectorAll(".open"), thisElement = item;

            if (openItems.length) {
                openItems.forEach(item => {
                  if (item !== thisElement) {
                      item.classList.remove("open");
                  }
                });
            }

            item.classList.toggle("open");
        });
    });
});
```

```css
* {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        body {
            font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
        }
        .container {
            width: 800px;
            margin: 2rem auto;
        }
        .accordion {
            display: flex;
        }
        .accordion__item {
            background: #ecf0f1;
            border-radius: 1rem;
            padding: 2rem;
            position: relative;
            max-height: 10px;
            z-index: 1;
            transition: all .6s ease;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin: .5rem;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .accordion__item::before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            z-index: 2;
            background: #3498db;
        }
        .accordion__item.open {
            max-height: 800px;
        }
        .accordion__item.open::before {
            background: transparent;
        }
```

```html
<div class="accordion" bke-data="accordion">
            <div class="accordion__item">
                <div class="accordion__topbar">
                    <p class="accordion__text">How long does delivery take?</p>
                    <span class="accordion__arrow"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion__box">
                    <p class="accordion__content">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque perspiciatis inventore
                        sapiente commodi id consectetur ducimus ipsa fugiat officiis nesciunt blanditiis
                        temporibus quas aperiam, voluptas.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion__item">
                <div class="accordion__topbar">
                    <p class="accordion__text">How long do I have to return my purchase?</p>
                    <span class="accordion__arrow"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion__box">
                    <p class="accordion__content">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque perspiciatis inventore
                        sapiente commodi id consectetur ducimus ipsa fugiat officiis nesciunt blanditiis
                        temporibus quas aperiam, voluptas.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion__item">
                <div class="accordion__topbar">
                    <p class="accordion__text">I ordered too many, can I update my order?</p>
                    <span class="accordion__arrow"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion__box">
                    <p class="accordion__content">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque perspiciatis inventore
                        sapiente commodi id consectetur ducimus ipsa fugiat officiis nesciunt blanditiis
                        temporibus quas aperiam, voluptas.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example finally learned something from it.

Comment: Hey @Galanthus, I just made an edit that maintains the functionality you need - sorry I must have misread your initial post. I've set a new variable `thisElement = item`, this means the `.remove('open')` will be ignored and standard functionality is restored. If that makes any sense :)

Comment: adding the item.classList.toggle('open') before the openItems.length does the job. can you check?

Answer (score 2):

So you're missing a lot of code above (and explanation) for this to be an effective answer.  However, I'll provide you with what *I* would do (without knowing what accordion plugin/tool you're using) and you can apply it however you want.

First, I would Inspect the HTML of the Container that houses your accordions. I'd click on one of them and watch to see if the `class` definition changes based on wether or not they are open or closed.

If there is a global class that gets applied to track the state of an open/closed accordion, then the simple answer is that `onClick` of the new container, you'd apply the same logic that occurs when it closes to all of them by using a global selector.

Now, if that doesn't work, you're probably dealing with something that's storing stuff into a data object on the elements themselves. You'll have to either just *know* which elements that data is stored on and inspect them (while toggling) or you'll have to write a routine to inspect each one and find the data - and then finally go back again to monitoring and watching.  You'd then update your `onClick` to make the necessary changes.

However, I am pretty sure this is a plugin of some sort, so I have a sneaky suspicion that if you just read their documentation that they'll provide you with all you need to know regarding how to manually toggle one/many accordions (or reset them all).

TLDR; next time give us a little more information to go on and we can help better!

Comment: Yeah, understand. But thought it would be an easy one. Actually trying to remove the previous sibling element if the current active is open and you click on the next on the previous one should be closed. I have attached some HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the HTML.  Can you also provide a link to the plugin you're using for accordions?  If it is an in-house built accordion, please state so as well. We might have to see that code to understand how it works before we can help you see.